# Russell's definite description and vacuous truth: a puzzle?

Tags: lo.logic, puzzle

According to Russell's definite description theory, "The present King of France is bald" is a false statement. However, since for any property $P$, $P$ is true for the elements of the empty set, the sentence "The present king of France is bald" should be true, since there is not a king of France that is not bold. How to reconcile the two?

Comment: I think this would be a better fit at philosophy.stackexchange.

Comment: You claim falsly that the statement "The present King of France is bald" takes the form $P(\emptyset)$ where $P$ is the baldness property. It rather takes the form $\exists! x \in K \,.\, P(x)$ where $K$ is the set of all present Kings of France. And because $K = \emptyset$ we get $\exists! x \in \emptyset . P(x)$, which is false. (Also, this is not a research-level question in mathematics.)

Comment: What **mathematical** argument compels you to interpret the English sentence "**The** present king of France is bold" as "**Every** present king of France is bald"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this question will stay open, but here I am and this is a question that leads to some interesting issues about reference and language. (But probably it should have been asked on philosophy.stackexchange.com.)

The answer is that Russell's theory of definite descriptions has to do with the use of "the" in the statement. His theory is that any statement at all about "the K" implies that there is such a thing as the unique thing with property K. Since there is no present king of France, any primitive assertion making reference to "the present king of France" will be false on Russell's account of reference.

According to Russell's theory, both of the statements

> The present king of France is bald

and

> The present king of France is non-bald

are false.

But there are some quirky subtleties to the theory. For example, if you apply negation on the outside of the first statement, you get the following:

> It is not the case that the present king of France is bald.

This comes out as true, since it is the negation of a false sentence. Sometimes  people introduce some special operators to enable us to express things a bit more precisely. For example, the iota operator $\iota x.Kx$ means the unique $x$ with property $K$, if there is one. And $\lambda x.Bx$ refers to the property of having property $B$.

So $$B(\iota x.Kx)$$
is false, because it asserts of the present king of France has the property of being bald. Whereas
$$\neg B(\iota x.Kx)$$
is true, because it asserts that it is not the case that the present king of France is bald.

But $$(\lambda x.\neg Bx)(\iota x.Kx)$$
is false, because it asserts of the present king of France that he has the property of being nonbald.

Comment: My own inclination is generally to take assertions with a failed definite descriptor term as meaningless. This aligns a little with Strawson (the eponym of my position), who held in contrast to Russell that uses of such terms presuppose their meaningfulness.